# Django unable to create tables for unit testing after upgrade from 1.8 to 2.2.4

Tags: django, django-models, django-testing, django-settings, django-2.2

After a successful upgrade from Django 1.8 to Django 2.2.4, when 
I run the tests it fails because Django does not create the database tables.

My test_settings.py file was working appropriately before the upgrade.

after debugging the Django db/backends it looks like the connection was created, but the tables were not. 
my suspicion is that test_setting.py is not configured well, although I copied everything from the setting.py file except the database configuration (that remained SQLite).

database configuration:

```
DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.sqlite3',
        'NAME': 'test_database'
    }
}
```

```
INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.sites',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    'rest_framework',
    'rest_framework.authtoken',
    'my_app',
    'mptt',
    'corsheaders',
    # audit app
    'easyaudit',
    'kronos',
    'django.contrib.admin',
]
```

The traceback that I'm getting (here it's, for example, the auth_user, but it reproduces for all the tables the same way):

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\owner\Desktop\workspace\my_project\MyProject\services\tests\test_logging.py", line 33, in setUpClass
    cls.user = User.objects.get_or_create(username='logging_test_user', password='test_password')
  File "C:\Users\owner\Desktop\workspace\my_project\venv36\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\manager.py", line 82, in manager_method
    return getattr(self.get_queryset(), name)(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\owner\Desktop\workspace\my_project\venv36\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\query.py", line 538, in get_or_create
    return self.get(**kwargs), False
  File "C:\Users\owner\Desktop\workspace\my_project\venv36\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\query.py", line 402, in get
    num = len(clone)
  File "C:\Users\owner\Desktop\workspace\my_project\venv36\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\query.py", line 256, in __len__
    self._fetch_all()
  File "C:\Users\owner\Desktop\workspace\my_project\venv36\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\query.py", line 1242, in _fetch_all
    self._result_cache = list(self._iterable_class(self))
  File "C:\Users\owner\Desktop\workspace\my_project\venv36\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\query.py", line 55, in __iter__
    results = compiler.execute_sql(chunked_fetch=self.chunked_fetch, chunk_size=self.chunk_size)
  File "C:\Users\owner\Desktop\workspace\my_project\venv36\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\sql\compiler.py", line 1100, in execute_sql
    cursor.execute(sql, params)
  File "C:\Users\owner\Desktop\workspace\my_project\venv36\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\utils.py", line 67, in execute
    return self._execute_with_wrappers(sql, params, many=False, executor=self._execute)
  File "C:\Users\owner\Desktop\workspace\my_project\venv36\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\utils.py", line 76, in _execute_with_wrappers
    return executor(sql, params, many, context)
  File "C:\Users\owner\Desktop\workspace\my_project\venv36\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\utils.py", line 84, in _execute
    return self.cursor.execute(sql, params)
  File "C:\Users\owner\Desktop\workspace\my_project\venv36\lib\site-packages\django\db\utils.py", line 89, in __exit__
    raise dj_exc_value.with_traceback(traceback) from exc_value
  File "C:\Users\owner\Desktop\workspace\my_project\venv36\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\utils.py", line 84, in _execute
    return self.cursor.execute(sql, params)
  File "C:\Users\owner\Desktop\workspace\my_project\venv36\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\sqlite3\base.py", line 383, in execute
    return Database.Cursor.execute(self, query, params)
django.db.utils.OperationalError: no such table: auth_user
```

The tests getting executed with the environment variables of

```
DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE=MyProject.test_settings
```

Comment: Do you see "Creating test database for alias 'default'..." when running your tests?

Comment: Also what's your development/production database? Why not use the same for your tests anyway? If you're using a PostgreSQL db for example and using specific pg functionalities like a `JSONField`, your tests will fail.

Comment: I do not see it in my environment, but in my colleague, it got displayed, but still gets the same error. my development database is PostgreSQL. We are not using JSONField so it isn't a problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It seems that there is a bug in django in this version (also since 2.2 maybe before, I didn't check more than that).

```
    databases = self.get_databases(suite)
    old_config = self.setup_databases(aliases=databases)
```

databases variable in here wont be None in no case because in the get_databases function it calls to _get_databases() and incase it won't find any databases that got configured like it mention above, databases will set to set(), and that in setup_databases function there's a function called

```
get_unique_databases_and_mirrors
```

that check if there's is not database configured in the tests, and if not it will take the databases that configured in the settings file, but because its set to an empty set (set()) than it wont get into this condition, and therefore no database will get created.

to pass that bug, you can create a class that will inherit unittests.Testcase, and configure the database like this:

```
import django
import unittest
from django.conf import settings


class MyTestCase(unittest.TestCase):
    databases = settings.DATABASES

    @classmethod
    def setUpClass(cls) -> None:
        super(MyTestCase, cls).setUpClass()
        django.setup()
```

Answer (score 1):

Somewhere along the line it became required for the databases used by test cases to be attached to them. Before instantiating the test database, Django makes a list of all the databases which will be required based upon the objects. After this it makes the schemas for them.

If you add to the base class you are inheriting from for all your tests, or to each class you subclass from the Django classes a line like:

```
databases = settings.DATABASES
```

you will find that your databases should instantiate.

Comment: Thank you, Dylan. little bit of correction: instead of sending the DB name, you need to send the database dictionary itself. you can make generic by sending settings.DATABASES while the settings are from django.conf import settings